How do I automate the collection of file size data from multiple remote machines?
I’m working on automating the collection of file sizes (EXAMPLE.ENG) from
D:\Dump\logs\default\Rk7\base\

across more than 140 machines on the same subnet and writing the results (including IP addresses) to an Excel spreadsheet. The machines are accessible via TeamViewer/VPN, and I'm trying to achieve this using PowerShell.
I've written the following minimal version of my script to gather the file size data, but it’s not working as expected. It either writes the headers Computer,FileSize(Bytes) without the actual file sizes or throws an error indicating the file can't be found. I’d appreciate any guidance on where I’m going wrong.
Here’s the script:
$targetIP = "10.168.0.45"
$remotePath = "D:\Dump\logs\default\Rk7\base\EXAMPLE.ENG"
$resultPath = "C:\result.csv"

if (-not (Test-Path $resultPath)) {
    "Computer,FileSize(Bytes)" | Out-File -FilePath $resultPath -Encoding utf8
}

$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials for remote access to $targetIP"

if ($null -eq $credential) {
    Write-Host "Error: Credential is null. Please provide valid credentials."
    exit
}

try {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $targetIP -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop
    
    $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        param($path)
        if (Test-Path $path) {
            $fileInfo = Get-Item $path -ErrorAction Stop
            return $fileInfo.Length
        } else {
            throw "File not found at the specified path: $path"
        }
    } -ArgumentList $remotePath
    
    "$targetIP,$result" | Out-File -FilePath $resultPath -Append -Encoding utf8
    Write-Host "Processed $targetIP: File size is $result bytes" -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = "Error processing ${targetIP}: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host $errorMessage -ForegroundColor Red
    "$targetIP,Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File -FilePath $resultPath -Append -Encoding utf8
}
finally {
    Remove-PSSession -Session $session -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Write-Host "Process completed. Results saved to $resultPath"

Specific Problems:

The script runs but does not collect or write the correct file sizes.

Errors like:
Error processing 10.168.0.45: File not found at the specified path: \\10.168.0.45\D$\D:\Dump\logs\files\EXAMPLE.ENG

Sometimes, only headers Computer,FileSize(Bytes) are written to the file without actual data.


Environment:

Machines are accessible via VPN or TeamViewer.

Running on Windows 11 using PowerShell 5.1.


Questions:

Should I continue debugging this PowerShell script, or am I missing something obvious that could simplify the process?

Can someone help me troubleshoot the file access and ensure correct file size collection?



Path error: \\10.168.0.45\D$\D:\Dump\logs\files\EXAMPLE.ENG should be \\10.168.0.45\D$\Dump\logs\files\EXAMPLE.ENG

Since you say all machines are on the same subnet, I would get the info by reading the file length directly using UNC paths, like \\10.168.0.45\D$\Dump\logs\files\EXAMPLE.ENG.
Try
$targetIP   = '10.168.0.45', '10.168.0.30', '10.168.0.47'        # etc. array of computernames or IP addresses
$remotePath = '\\{0}\D$\Dump\logs\default\Rk7\base\EXAMPLE.ENG'  # template path where the computer's name or IP gets filled in
$resultPath = 'C:\result.csv'                                    # path for the resulting csv file on YOUR machine
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials for remote access to $targetIP"

# loop over the computers in the $targetIP array and collect the wanted info
$result = foreach ($computer in $targetIP) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {   # if needed add  -Credential $credential
        # create the path to the file. i.e. \\10.168.0.45\D$\Dump\logs\default\Rk7\base\EXAMPLE.ENG
        $filePath = $remotePath -f $computer
        $fileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # if needed add  -Credential $credential
        if ($fileInfo) {
            # output an object with the wanted properties to be collected in variable $result
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'Computer'        = $computer
                'FileSize(Bytes)' = $fileInfo.Length
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "File $filePath not found.."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $computer is not reachable.."
    }
}

# finally, write the $results to a CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $resultPath -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

